# Adding, filling the table column within one migration Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I'm trying to fulfill such migration:

```
class AddColumn1AndColumn2ToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :models do |t|
      t.string :column1, default: "FFFFFFFF"
      t.integer :column2
    end
    
    Model.where(name: 'Name1').each{|model| model.update_columns(column1: '00000000', column2: 1)}
    Model.where(name: 'Name2').each{|model| model.update_columns(column1: '00000000', column2: 1)}
    Model.where(name: 'Name3').each{|model| model.update_columns(column1: 'FFFFFFFF', column2: model.mod_index.to_i(16))}
  end
end
```

But I get such a mistake:

```
== 20210503012429 AddColumn1AndColumn2ToModel: migrating ========
-- change_table(:models)
   -> 0.0038s
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

can't write unknown attribute `column1`
```

I tried to change Change_table to add_column, but the error is the same.

```
add_column :models, :column1, :string, default: 'FFFFFFFF' 
add_column :models, :column2, :integer
```

How can I add columns to the table in migration and immediately change them?

Comment: The question has the <sql> tag, but I see no SQL at all above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `#reset_column_information`. Could be that the old schema information is still cached.

```rb
class AddColumn1AndColumn2ToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    change_table :models do |t|
      t.string :column1, default: "FFFFFFFF"
      t.integer :column2
    end

    Model.reset_column_information
    
    Model.where(name: 'Name1').each{|model| model.update_columns(column1: '00000000', column2: 1)}
    Model.where(name: 'Name2').each{|model| model.update_columns(column1: '00000000', column2: 1)}
    Model.where(name: 'Name3').each{|model| model.update_columns(column1: 'FFFFFFFF', column2: model.mod_index.to_i(16))}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you my dear friend! It helped me!